# How to set pattern or format for a input

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2-advanced-app

I have two input field 
i want to set my first input field format like ASED0000A

if i enter value AAAA or input other character like A to Z then, the other keys are disabled

Input should be in the following format:
1st 4 should be alphabets
The next four should be numeric
The last should be an aplhabet

And my second input field format is like AAA/AA/000/0
1st 3 input is character then a slash (/)

The other 2 input is characters then a slash(/)

The next 3 is number and again a slash and the la
st a single digit.

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'pan_number')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'AAAAOOOOA','style'=>"text-transform:uppercase"])->label('PAN') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'tds_ao')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'AAA/AA/OOO/O'])->label('TDS circle/AO code') ?>
<script>

      $('#companytexinfo-pan_number').keypress(function(e){
            var inputval = $('#companytexinfo-pan_number').val().length;
            console.log(inputval);
            let allow_char = [65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,
                            105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122];
            if(inputval >=4){
                if(allow_char.indexOf(e.which) == -1 ){
                //do something
                }
                else{
                return false;
                }
            }
            let allow_number = [48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57];
            if((inputval >=5) && (inputval =8)){
                if(allow_number.indexOf(e.which) == -1 ){
                //do something
                }
                else{
                return false;
                }
            }
            let allow_alst_char = [65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,
                                105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122];
            if(inputval ==9){
                if(allow_alst_char.indexOf(e.which) == -1 ){
                    //do something
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
      })

</script>
```

this is my script but it's not work properly 
Please help 
thank

Comment: So what doesnt work exactly? What have you tried to debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [formatter.js](https://github.com/jaridmargolin/formatter.js?files=1) to achieve this.
Modify your input like below after adding the plugin.

```
    <input type="text" name="pan_number" id="pan_number"/>

    <script>

      $('#pan_number').formatter({
          'pattern': '{{aaaa}}{{9999}}{{a}}',
          'persistent': true
     });

    </script>
```